# Cannot insert/locate find .png picture

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have found some code online that I can use on my own project. It's fairly simple, but when I run the program, I get an error message that it can not find the resource.

I have tried a lot and simply can not see the error - I inserted pictures by saying: add -> new folder (right click) -> added all the images:

```
 int[] yourHandArray = yourHand.ToInt();
        int[] dealerHandArray = dealerHand.ToInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < yourHandArray.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: Card1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/img_cards/"+ (yourHandArray[i] + 1) + ".png")); break;
                case 1: Card2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/img_cards/" + (yourHandArray[i] + 1) + ".png")); break;
                case 2: Card3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/img_Cards/" + (yourHandArray[i] + 1) + ".png")); break;
                case 3: Card4.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/img_cards/" + (yourHandArray[i] + 1) + ".png")); break;
                case 4: Card5.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/img_cards/" + (yourHandArray[i] + 1) + ".png")); break;
                case 5: Card6.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/img_cards/" + (yourHandArray[i] + 1) + ".png")); break;
                case 6: Card7.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/img_cards/" + (yourHandArray[i] + 1) + ".png")); break;
            }
        }
```

[This is the folder I 
refer to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMs1u.png)

Comment: Is the build action of the new files correctly set to "Resource"?

Comment: Your code is far too complicated. Better put the Images elements in another array and write `Card[i].Source = new BitmapImage(...)` without the switch block. Besides that, make sure that the Build Action of the PNG files is set to Resource.

Comment: Yes the build action of the new files er set to "Resources" but still cant be found.

Comment: @Clemens That means I also have to change the XAML window and I can not see how to do that.

Comment: Why exactly change the XAML? You can easily add Card1 to Card7 to an array. However, much better would be an ItemsControl with the Image element in its ItemTemplate.

Comment: Also check if the image files are located in the correct project folders. With `pack://application:,,,/View/img_cards/...` they should be in a folder `img_cards` which itself is in a folder `View` in the root of the same project where you use them.

Comment: They are inserted as you describe, but still can not be found. Have I perhaps overlooked something else? @Clemens

Comment: @Clemens I have inserted a picture of my project --> 
Maybe you can see an error in it.

Comment: And this in the project of the application? Or is it in a class library?

Comment: @KlausGütter It is in a class library but the project have a reference to it and can use all the librarys cs. files and xamls.

Comment: You could try adding the assembly name of the class library to the URI: pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/View/img_cards/...

Comment: Just to be sure...
Should I replace 'MyAssembly' with the library name? And what about 'component' should it be changed to something specific? @KlausGütter

Comment: Yes, replace MyAssembly with the assembly name of the class library, keep the "component" as it is. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf

Comment: Thank you very much @KlausGütter!! 
It works :-)